# Смена цветовой гаммы элементов при использовании hover

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, hover

"Не подскажете, как сделать так, чтобы при наведение на элемент менял цвет, а остальные элементы затемнялись."

Хорошо, пойду проще, есть меню, в нем 5 элементов, наводя на один элемент курсор, он у меня меняет цвет, а остальные элементы в меню меняли цвет на другой.

Нету наработок, мне принцип понять. Если так будет проще, то вот список из 5 элементов

```
<div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href=""></a></li>
            <li><a href=""></a></li>
            <li><a href=""></a></li>
            <li><a href=""></a></li>
            <li><a href=""></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: у вас есть наработки от которых можно оттолкнуться?

Comment: Знаешь scss? я понял, что ты имел ввиду

Comment: Нет, scss не знаю

Comment: Хорошая штука!!! Рекомендую почитать. Это тот же css, только проще

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понял ты хотел добиться этого:
(*расскрой код и запусти его)*

```css
.nav ul:hover li > a {
  color: grey;
}
.nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
.nav ul li a:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Первое</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Второе</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Третье</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Четвертое</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Пятое</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Как реализовал я это в **`SCSS`**:

```
.nav{
  ul{
    &:hover li > a{
      color: grey;
    }
    li{
      a{
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;
        transition: all .2s ease-in-out;

        &:hover{
          color: red;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Как **`SCSS`** "переводит" код в нормальный **`CSS`**:

```
.nav ul:hover li > a {
  color: grey;
}
.nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
.nav ul li a:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, я думаю пока мне надо уверено себя чувствовать в css, без sass, less и т.д.

Comment: @GlebPristupa но я настоятельно рекомендую потом это пройти! очень поможет в будущем

Comment: это и есть sass?

Comment: @GlebPristupa ну по сути да. SASS/SCSS, но SCSS, на мой взгляд, удобнее

Answer (score 1):

```css
.nav ul {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    background: grey;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
}

.nav ul:hover {
    background: lightgray;
    color: blue;
}

.nav li {
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.nav a {
    display: block;
    color: red;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.nav a:hover {
    color: blue;
    background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```